# Getting list of all windows in current thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0, ui-thread

I am starting a new UI-Thread in my WPF-application. Now I am searching a way to get a list with all windows in this thread - like I will get it for the main-thread with `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows`.
Is there something in the .NET-Framework or does I have to implement it myself? When I have to implement it myself, perhaps someone have little bit of sample-code?

Comment: why are you starting a new ui thread? that will just complicate things.

Comment: That is a long story - but it is necessary. All is working great now - But I have now to get the window, which is open in the second UI-Thread to set it as Owner for a new Window which I open in this second UI-Thread.

Comment: `Application.Current.Windows` should **EDIT** not return the windows for the current thread only.  Each thread should have its own application.  (I haven't checked that)

Comment: @SLaks: According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx) it's per AppDomain and not per Thread

Comment: Then I take that back.  I believe that WinForms is per-thread.

Comment: `Windows`: This property is available only from the thread that created the Application object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx):

> A Window reference is automatically added to Windows as soon as a window is instantiated on the user interface (UI) thread; windows that are created by worker threads are not added. A Window reference is automatically removed after its Closing event has been handled and before its Closed event is raised.
>
> By default, the first item added to the Windows property becomes the MainWindow.
>
> This property is available only from the thread that created the Application object.

So it seems the windows created by worker threads are not hold in any collection automatically. I assume you create that window on the worker thread - so you should store a reference to it yourself for later access (you could do that in the Windows constructor by adding `this` to some window manager class)